# Null Pointer Exception - GoogleAuthUtil Authentication on Google Account in Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception

I am working on an app that, among other things, authenticates with Google to grab a user's profile picture and name from their Google account. At present, I am just trying to print out the token received from Google as a debug measure, to verify that it is working that far. However, I consistently have a null token (it doesn't appear to be set at all), giving the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
com.sp.norsesquare.froyo.NorseSquare$LoginAsyncTask.doInBackground(NS.java:465)
com.sp.norsesquare.froyo.NorseSquare$LoginAsyncTask.doInBackground(NS.java:1)
android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

I am using an custom AsyncTask class to get the data and return it to the main activity, this is defined as a public class within the main activity.

```
public class LoginAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{
NS ns;
String email;
String mScope;
String authToken;
Context context;
Bundle bundle;

public LoginAsyncTask(String e)
{
    email = e;
    bundle = new Bundle();
}

protected void onPreExecute()
{
    Log.i("BEGIN","Getting authtoken");
}

protected String doInBackground(String... args)
{
    try 
    {
        authToken = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(context, email, "oauth2:"+"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile", bundle);
        Log.i("MESSAGEGEGEGE","YOUR TOKEN = "+authToken);

    }
    catch (UserRecoverableAuthException recoverableException) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "UserRecoverableException Occurred", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.e("GOOGLEAUTH","UserRecoverableException Triggered");
         Intent recoveryIntent = recoverableException.getIntent();


     } catch (GoogleAuthException authEx) {

         Log.e("MESSAAGEGEG", "Unrecoverable authentication exception: " + authEx.getMessage(), authEx);
     } catch (IOException ioEx) {
         Log.i("MESSAGEGEGE", "transient error encountered: " + ioEx.getMessage());

     }
       catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
    return authToken;
}

protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress)
{
    Log.i("PROGRESS","Getting somewhere");
}

protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
{

    Log.i("GOOGLEAUTH", "Returning Received Google Token");
    googleAuthToken = result;
        //This is a variable defined in the main activity
    }


}
```

I am somewhat lost as to where this is coming from, and cannot find anything anywhere. I would deeply appreciate your help, thanks!

Comment: Looks like the `Context context` is null.

Comment: Since when did the GoogleAuthUtil.getToken() method start throwing a GoogleAuthException with message "BadUsername" for an email that is not registered on a device, instead of the previous exception IllegalArgumentException with message "Non existing account 'email_address'" ?  
http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthUtil.html#getToken(android.content.Context , java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

Comment: This used to work for me, but only a few days ago it stopped working and now it throws this error com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException: Unknown. Any idea why? Is there something wrong with my scopes? https://gist.github.com/lawloretienne/7351151

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Arhimed, the context you're passing to `getToken()` is likely null. This happened to me when I was cobbling some things together for quick and dirty testing. Passing it a valid context resolved the error.